# Space not appearing in the Text Box

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my Web Application I have a text box as:

```
<td id='even1'><input name="txteskemail" id="txteskemail1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_maintaincontractcontact['Email']; ?>"></td>
```

The problem is when I echo the field directly from the database using the record set I am getting the output as
    **Jong-Si@abc.com Ji-yo@xyz.com** mind the space between the 2 mail Id's.But when I am displaying the same in the text box I am getting this as **Jong-Si@abc.comJi-yo@xyz.com** without space.I am unable to figure out why.please help me.

Comment: Use var_dump to check your variable

Comment: Copy the value from the generated text box and paste it into your notepad. If you see the spaces there, then maybe there's a CSS issue with you field.

Comment: Even in the notepad I am not seeing any space,But in the database I have the space ;(